# Representing sentence types with UML diagram

Tags: uml

I want to create a uml diagram that can represent sentences as the one below:

"On 21/03/2020, baker A purchased from the flour company B 20 Kg of type AAA flour for 1.20 euros per kg, that he later used to produce 70 pieces of bread that he then sold to different costumers of his shop on 23/03/2020 with the price of 1.10 euro per piece."

Below you can see my first thoughts. This is quite general, I haven't added attributes yet. My problem is that I'm not sure how to represent that 2 different people make the transaction, the buyer (ie baker A) and the seller(company B), and how to show that someone (ie baker A) can be both a buyer(ie he buys from B) and a seller (ie A sells bread to costumers):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend to have some basic UML course before starting this. The above isn't UML. One might recognize classes and associations. The big arrows are probably meat as generalization. Wrong notation. Same for the Y-shaped asociations. Maybe you mean an association class but then it would be ProductPrice.

Comment: @qwerty_so I know about UML, not an expert though. I know this is not a uml diagram and the problem is that the teacher said just create a uml diagram without saying what kind of uml, plus I had in mind another general model I saw in the lectures that was close to what the exercises now asks me to do. I will ask her and make a real uml

Answer (score 0):

First notice that a UML Class Diagram can only represent ***sentence types***, but not a specific sentence, which could, however, be represented by what is called an 'Object Diagram'.

> How to represent that 2 different people make the transaction, the
>   buyer (ie baker A) and the seller(company B)

You have already represented this in your second class diagram with the associations between `Buyer`/`Seller` and `Transaction`, but since you've also defined `Buyer` and `Seller` to form an overlapping segmentation of `Trader`, you need to attach a constraint "buyer is distinct from seller" to your `Transaction` class.

For completeness, you should also add multiplicities at both ends of these two one-to-many associations ( a "1" at the `Buyer`/`Seller` end, and a "*" at the `Transaction` end).

> How to show that someone (ie baker A) can be both a buyer(ie he buys
>   from B) and a seller (ie A sells bread to costumers)

This is already possible according to your second diagram where every `Buyer` and `Seller` is a `Trader`, and this segmentation is overlapping (by default), and therefore a trader can be a buyer in one transaction and a seller in another one.

Comment: Hi Gerd, the constraint that the sentence expresses (buyer and seller not being the same person) is not the same as the one enforced by the multiplicities you suggested (transactions having one buyer and one seller). The last sentence replicates my answer.

Comment: @observer: You are right, this constraint has to be expressed by an additional OCL invariant, which I should add to my answer. Your remark, "just add them as attributes", doesn't help here.

Answer (score -1):

There are many more diagram types than class diagrams. Do you have any constraint that it must only be *one* diagram? If so, why? Each diagram type focuses on a particular view onto the system under design, so they go together. It is not the purpose of UML to reflect *all* information in just one diagram. For example, try to complement your diagram with an acitivity diagram or sequence diagram. You'll find it helpful.

> how to show that someone (ie baker A) can be both a buyer(ie he buys from B) and a seller (ie A sells bread to costumers)

You did that already with the abstraction of the `Trader`.

> I'm not sure how to represent that 2 different people make the transaction, the buyer (ie baker A) and the seller(company B)

Just add them to `Transaction` as attributes.

Hint: The relation "Unit / Price / Product" is not UML compliant.

Comment: That Y-shaped association is probably compliant (I don't know any constraint; if you know one, can you please specify the UML reference) but just confusing. Usually people use overlays for generalization but you can also bend/overlay associations. When done like in OP's drawing it's just confusing since you don't know where which association ends.

Comment: I was seeing it as one single association between 3 classes at once.

Comment: You may have missed the requirement. Representing sentences requires defining a vocabulary (or a predicate logic signature), which can only be done with Class Models, where classes define unary predicates and associations define binary or n-ary predicates.

Comment: No, I didn't miss the requirement, Gerd. Clearly it's more a beginner-level question, therefore I believe that I have chosen appropriate level of detail and wording.

Comment: Again: only a class model can represent a vocabulary, while you suggest looking at other kinds of UML models as well, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I suspect we misunderstand each other. The part about the vocabulary is your interpretation of the OP's question. Can you cite a source that tells how state diagrams or component diagrams are NOT a valid way to turn a given sentence in natural language into an adequate UML representation?

Comment: We should better leave the clarification of the OP's question to the OP.